# ceph-radosgw charm with ssl

Tags: juju, ceph

Is there a way to setup juju's ceph-radosgw to use HTTPS (using only charms)?
I had a look at haproxy (to do SSL-offload), but haproxy doesn't seem to have a way of giving it a VIP or name to listen on.

I would like the radosgw to be visible at 'https://store.mydomain.com'